# How to get only numeric column values?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

I want to get only numeric values from the table

Column1

```
12345
asdf
2312
ase
acd
...,
```

Tried Query

```
Select Isnumeric(column1) from table
```

Showing Result as

```
1
0
1
0
0
..,
```

I need the colum1 numeric value

Need SQL Server Query help

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(column1) = 1
```

Note, as [Damien_The_Unbeliever has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858966/33453), this will include any [valid numeric type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186272.aspx).

To filter out columns containing non-digit characters (and empty strings), you could use

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column1 not like '%[^0-9]%' and column1 != ''
```

Answer (score 41):

The other answers indicating using IsNumeric in the where clause are correct, as far as they go, but it's important to remember that it returns 1 if the value can be converted to *any* numeric type. As such, oddities such as "1d3" will make it through the filter.

If you need only values composed of digits, search for that explicitly:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column1 not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

The above is filtering to reject any column which contains a non-digit character

Note that in any case, you're going to incur a table scan, indexes are useless for this sort of query.

Comment: Note that `not like '%[^0-9]%'` does not filter out blank values. If you do not want to include empty strings, you need to add additional check.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE Isnumeric(column1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This [Tested]

To **get numeric**

```
SELECT column1
FROM table
WHERE Isnumeric(column1) = 1; // will return Numeric values
```

To **get non-numeric**

```
SELECT column1
FROM table
WHERE Isnumeric(column1) = 0; // will return non-numeric values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column1 not like '%[0-9]%'
```

Removing the '^' did it for me. I'm looking at a varchar field and when I included the ^ it excluded all of my non-numerics which is exactly what I didn't want. So, by removing ^ I only got non-numeric values back.