# How can I search for numbers in a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a simple nvarchar(25) column in an SQL database table. Most of the time, this field should contain alphanumeric text. However, due to operator error, there are many instances where it contains only a number. Can I do a simple search in SQL to identify these cases? That is, determine which rows in the table contain only digits in this column. As an extension, could I also search for those column values which contain only digits and a space and/or slash.

In other languages (eg. Perl, Java) a regular expression would resolve this quickly and easily. But I haven't been able to find the equivalent in SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858867/how-to-get-only-numeric-column-values

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't work. Try `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1E2'),ISNUMERIC('1D2')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can achive this by using isnumeric function available in sql sever

check more at this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Cool. What if I want to search for "30/23" for example?

Comment: In SQL 2000; thats going to be hard. In 2005 and up I would say use Regex.

Comment: The isnumeric function is not good here, because isnumeric('787315689001e180') is true, however the input contains an 'e', which is not a digit.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers referred to the isnumeric function, but they are not correct, I've mentioned in a comment for all the answers the flaw in the answers. The correct solution is to use a regular expression in your where clause, which contains not like '%[^0-9]%', see the example below:

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select column_name from table_name where IsNumeric(column_name) <> 1
```

Comment: The isnumeric function is not good here, because isnumeric('787315689001e180') is true, however the input contains an 'e', which is not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric Only:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1
```

With Space:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field LIKE '% %'
```

With Slash:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field LIKE '%/%'
```

Combined:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1 OR  Field LIKE '% %' OR Field LIKE '%/%'
```

Comment: The isnumeric function is not good here, because isnumeric('787315689001e180') is true, however the input contains an 'e', which is not a digit.