# T-SQL query where column only contains numbers

Tags: t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get only numeric column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858867/how-to-get-only-numeric-column-values)

I am trying to write a T-SQL query that only returns rows where a specific column only contains numbers.

something like

select * from table where column like '[0-9]%'

The problem is the column can be 1 - 10 characters long.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourColumn NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Actually, the Carat is a "not" so it returns those rows that AREN'T all numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is why @LukeH also introduced a `NOT` in there. It works as expected!

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`IsNumeric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function:

```
select * from table where IsNumeric(column) = 1
```

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the column should only contain the characters `0` to `9`. The `ISNUMERIC` function will match if the column contains things like `1.75`, `-34`, `+96.28` etc.