# How do I get only the numeric values in SQL Server (ISNUMERIC not giving correct values)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table called 'testTable' with two columns, 'id' that is auto incremented and 'someValue'.

The data contained in the 'someValue' column are: `12, 1.2, .4, 1d4, +, -, .`

I want to select only the numeric values. But when I use the following query:

```
SELECT someValue, ISNUMERIC(someValue) 
FROM testTable;
```

all the values are true. And for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM testTable 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(someValue) = 1;
```

all the values are being returned.

I just want `12`, `1.2` and `.4` .

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE:

The data type for the column `someValue` is `varchar(50)`.

Comment: what is the data type of `someValue`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to only select numeric data from mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756736/how-to-only-select-numeric-data-from-mysql)

Comment: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html

Comment: @njk This is SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1858966/679449) seems viable.

Comment: @njk Isnumeric is not working as expected.

Comment: @Harke You tried `SELECT ... WHERE column1 not like '%[^0-9]%'` ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is there a build in function for regular expression in MSSQL or creating a function is the only way?

Comment: It should be `'%[^0-9.]%` to allow the decimal values

Comment: @njk Yes. But then it won't for values with '1d4'. It selects these types of values.

Comment: @Harke - no it doesn't; using `not like '%[^0-9]%` would only select **12** from your example and nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SETUP:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
  ID INT,
  Value NVARCHAR(250)
)


INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (1, '12')
INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (2, '1.2')
INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (3, '.4')
INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (4, '1d4')
INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (5, '+')
INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (6, '-')
INSERT INTO SomeTable (ID, Value) VALUES (7, '.')
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(Value+'d0')=1
```

RESULT:

```
ID  VALUE
1   12
2   1.2
3   .4
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But could you explain how it worked. What does ISNUMERIC(Value+'d0') do? What significance does 'd0' have?